# Hide div on blur via jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, blur

I'm trying to create the illusion of a multiselect dropdown using a div that is toggled by pressing an empty dropdown. It works fine but I'd like to be able to hide it when clicking outside the div. How do I do this? I use the following code:

```
<script src="../js/jqGlobal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".testColor").click(function () {
            $("#exampleDiv").toggle();
        });
        $("#exampleDiv").blur(function () {
            $("#exampleDiv").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #exampleDiv 
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:22px;
        left: 0px;
        width:198px;
        height:150px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
        display: none;
    }

</style>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200" class="testColor">

        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div id="exampleDiv">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox11" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox12" runat="server" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Click outside and other interesting events for jquery: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick any where on the page hide the div and cancel click propagation to parent elements when click on testColor

```
function cancelBubleEv(e)
{
     e = e||event;
     e.stopPropagation? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;

}

$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).click(function () {

        $("#exampleDiv").hide();

     });
     $(".testColor").click(function (e) {
         $("#exampleDiv").toggle();
         cancelBubleEv(e);
     });
     $("#exampleDiv").click(function (e) {
        cancelBubleEv(e);
     });

});
```

Edit:

Cancel event propagation when click on checkboxes

Comment: That code hides it when I press a checkbox as well. Is it tweakable?

Comment: sorry, i just forgot about that you can cancel bubble event on checkbox as well. i have edited the code.

Comment: this should work fine, did you added the code inside this $(document).ready(function () { }); block if not then add it in this block, i edited the code copy this code

Comment: Yes, I did. It keeps jumping all over the place.

Comment: If I just past your edit the toggle doesn't show the div in the first place.

Comment: I haven't change position or any css property,  i just show/hide div, this code working fine for me

Comment: Thanks! I just can't see why this doesn't work for me. I've put it on a new blank HTML page, copied the code but it still doesn't work. When I click the text nothing happens.

Comment: Turns out a unicode character caused the code not working. Once removed your solution worked just the way I wanted it to. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $("#exampleDiv");    

$(document).bind('mouseup', function (e){
     if (element.has(e.target).length === 0)
         $(element).hide();
});

$(element).click(function(){
    $(element).show();
})
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with that code. Is it missing a )? Sorry to have to ask but I'm not that good with jQuery.

Comment: Hey, now we're getting close! It works the way I'd like it to now except that when clicking the body of the div, i.e. missing a checkbox, the div disappears. Is it possible to remove that event from the #exampleDiv?

Comment: I think now it's exactly what you wished for. I hope i helped you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try .mouseout() instead of .blur()

Comment: Mouse out makes it jump a lot back and forth while moving the mouse over the controls inside of it.